CKEditor 5 delete custom element on click
I am trying to delete an element with a certain class after it is clicked in CKEditor.
I tried both the vanilla javascript to remove it from the DOM and the model.change way in CKEditor.
For some reason neither way works and the element is still there.
// onclick edit with ballon
editor.editing.view.document.on('click', (evt, data) => {
    const clickedElement = data.domTarget;

    // Check if the clicked element matches the element you inserted
    if (clickedElement.classList.contains('dl-element')) {
        //Get data
        let dtValue = "";
        let ddValue = "";
        for(const child of data.domTarget.children) {
            if(child.className.includes("dt-element")) {
                dtValue = child.innerHTML;
            } else if(child.className.includes("dd-element")) {
                ddValue = child.innerHTML;
            }
        }

        // pass data to ui
        this._showUIWithData(dtValue, ddValue)

        // Remove old element from dom
        editor.model.document.model.deleteContent(clickedElement);
        editor.model.change(writer => {
            writer.remove(modelElement);
        });
    }
});


What am I doing wrong?
